# sorted() function behavior with and without mapping

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

code part one:

```
joint_pair = [[8, -4, -2, 5], [2, 4, -1, -3]]

print(sorted(joint_pair))
```

the code returns the sorted list  without touching the values inside the nested lists.

```
[[2, 4, -1, -3], [8, -4, -2, 5]]
```

code part two:

```
new_pairs = map(lambda p: sorted(p), joint_pair)
print(list(new_pairs))
```

in this case the sequence of the nested lists is not touched but the numbers inside the lists are sorted.

```
[[-4, -2, 5, 8], [-3, -1, 2, 4]]
```

Am I not applying the sorted() method in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

No, you're not using `sorted()` equivalently between the two.

Code 1 sorts the outer list (which contains two lists) by comparing the lists to each other.

Code 2 sorts the inner lists by comparing their contents (the numbers), but doesn't sort the outer list afterwards (though it just so happens that it's already sorted).

The more Pythonic way to write that expression is `[sorted(p) for p in joint_pair]`, which IMO makes the intent more obvious.